# how does caching work in flex web application?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm new to Flex and want to learn about how to implement client-side caching for data that is repeatedly requested from the server.

Let's focus on a simple example to discuss caching. Take a Flex application having several screens, where each screen plots a line series (of x and y data). The user can switch between the screens, and each time a screen is visited or re-visited, numerical arrays for both x and y data are requested from the server. The values of the x and y data on the server, of course, never change.

I want to learn what techniques are available that could be used to implement caching in the browser or AIR application such that once the x and y data is downloaded the first time, the application pulls these arrays from cache when re-visiting this screen in the future.

How is this done?

Comment: Your question is not very concrete. There is no caching strategy that's best for all situations. The strategy to adopt will be determined by the requirements of your project and has to be evaluated on project per project basis.

Comment: I changed the question to be more concrete. I'm looking for more of the nuts and bolts (e.g. code) to implement caching rather than a qualitative strategy. If I wanted to cache an array that is downloaded from the server, how to do this?

Comment: Hi ggk,  Flex applications are persistent.  What this means is once the application is running it holds all the objects in RAM and only releases them when the garbage collector comes around and looks for orhpaned objects (those taking up memory but without any references to them from the application).  You can store your data in an ArrayCollection and reference it any time after it's initially fetched so long as the user doesn't reload the page/swf.

Comment: As such it's totally up to you when a request will be sent out to populate the ArrayCollection, it is in essence "automatically cached" though not in the sense that the server is caching the data but rather it's in memory on the client.  Normally caching is occuring to the client's hard disk instead with Flex you're just storing it in RAM, if you'd like to avoid a call to the service after a reload, you could as suggested below store the data in a local shared object (serialize the ArrayCollection and save to disk, then load from the SharedObject on start, give the user the option to update).

Comment: Thanks shaun, starting to make sense now. I'd be a little concerned that writing to the hard drive would be intrusive to the client, so storing in RAM is preferred (from a client's security perspective at least). But just so I understand correctly: caching to RAM when using ArrayCollection is default functionality, right? What if user goes to a new screen that no longer uses that data, is the data garbage collected? Or, does it persist in RAM for the entire session (assuming user doesn't click to reload the page in browser). That's really good news if so.

Comment: Also, is there a way to tell if an array has already been saved in RAM as an ArrayCollection (that is, it has already been downloaded), and thus there's no need to send out the request (again)? How to write an if statement to check for this (e.g. if no array exists in RAM, request data from server, otherwise, don't)?

Comment: Try not to look at a Flex app as a standard web app. There are no 'pages' that are generated by the server. You have one app on the client side that can change its view states, but is never reloaded when you do so. Data is loaded as you need it through services. The way to approach this is more desktop-app-like than traditional-web-app-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want to cache.
Swf's are cached by the browser. So swfs are not downloaded each time the browser points to your site.
If you want to remember what the user typed before on a screen or autocomplete or just cache non-sensitive data you could use a SharedObject. 
And then there's always the traditional way of storing the data you retrieve from the server in an ArrayCollection or some other object in memory and refer to it multiple times.

Comment: I changed the question to be more concrete, by focusing on numeric arrays (for example). Could you expand on the "traditional way of storing the data you retrieve from the server in an ArrayCollection or some other object in memory and refer to it multiple times"? Maybe my question is too simple (I may not have the experience to know better). But how is caching implemented here? Is is done automatically (behind the scenes) when using ArrayCollection? etc.